# How to duplicate a line in KDevelop

Tags: shortcut, kdevelop

How can I clone a line in KDevelop? Is there any shortcut or menu item for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To duplicate lines up/down, use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

To move lines up/down, use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

See *Editor->Tools->Scripts*.

This is all implemented in Kate using JavaScript and can easily be extended.

To reassign the shortcuts, see *Settings->Configure Shortcuts*.

Comment: Is it possible to change these key bindings? I could not find _Scripts_ under _Tools_ menu (KDevelop 4.2.3)

Comment: Thanks very much. On my Ubuntu 12.04 install, these shortcuts are hijacked by Unity to switch virtual desktops. Reassigning them worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to enable `Copy/Cut the current line if no selection` in `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Editing`.

Then you can <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> any line.